# Using external JAR files in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an android project and use Android Studio as IDE. How can I add external jar's to the build path or how can I use them?
My project is libGDX based, so I haven't `libs` folder in root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jar I was importing had been compiled/exported with Java 7 in mind. Once I enabled compliance with Java 6 it worked fine.

To sum it up, when adding an external jar file in Android Studio:

1. Copy jar to root/project/libs folder;
   2.Right-click and add as library;
   3.Add the jar to root/project/build.gradle (something like compile files('libs/test-jar-to-import.jar'));
   4.Make sure the imported jar complies with Java 6 (7 will not do, for now).